# get the most representative colour from the uppermost pixel of a picture (the sky colour)

Tags: imagemagick, rgb, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick

Using any language readily available under a UNIX system, I'd like to get the the representative RGB colour values for the uppermost pixels of a JPG file.

In other words, given an image file, I'd like to `-crop3072x1`, resize to `1x1` (obviously without preserving the aspect ratio), then get the RGB value of the resulting pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Using [GraphicsMagick](http://ports.su/graphics/GraphicsMagick), there's apparently a *TXT* image format that's available:

`gm convert IMG_X.JPG -crop x1 -resize 1x1\! txt:-`

For example:

```
% gm convert IMG_7753.JPG -crop 2800x1 -resize 1x1\! txt:-
0,0: ( 63,107,158) #3F6B9E
```

References:

- http://www.graphicsmagick.org/convert.html
- http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-crop
- http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-resize
- http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-geometry